# RedirectToAction With String Parameters

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I want to access to: Users/Account/Alex for example
So what I did is-

return RedirectToAction("Account", "Users", new { userName= userName });

BUT, i get this error :
Could not find this localhost page
‪https://localhost:44351/Users/Account?userName=Alex

Can someone please tell me what I do wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
return RedirectToAction("Account", "Users", new {id = userName });
```

Comment: You should explain *why* "trying this" would help at all. You're relying on the default configuration of the optional `{id}` route parameter, which the OP could have renamed